# Developer Licence error when running WinRT unit tests using vstest.console.exe from the command line

Tags: windows-runtime, mstest

I'm getting the following error when I try to execute WinRT MSTests from the command line:

```
EXEC : error : Could not start test run for unit tests for Windows Store app: No valid developer license found for running unit tests for Windows Store apps. Please install/renew your developer license..
```

This used to work, but has suddenly started failing. The odd thing is that they execute fine from within visual studio.

I'm using the following MSBuild task.

```
<Target Name="UnitTest" DependsOnTargets="Compile" >
       <ItemGroup>
        <TestAppx Include="$(SolutionDir)\**\*x86*\**\*Tests*.appx" />
       </ItemGroup>

    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running tests for %(TestAppx.Identity)" />

    <Exec Command='"$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" %(TestAppx.Identity) /InIsolation /platform:x86 /Logger:trx /UseVsixExtensions:true'
          WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionDir)"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

Still not exactly sure why VisualStudio and vstest were out-of-sync, but I found a solution.

- Open PowerShell as an administrator
- Execute: Unregister-WindowsDeveloperLicense
- Open the solution in visual studio
- Log in to your live account when prompted to re-create your developer licence

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx#getting_a_developer_license_at_a_command_prompt